# how can I design the deezer api query more precisely

Tags: python-3.x

I am getting a wrong edition here, can someone tell me how I can split it up

output:

```
album <Artist: Die Toten Hosen>
genres [<Genre: Alternative>, <Genre: Indie Rock>, <Genre: Pop>]
```

how can i change it to look like this:

```
album Die Toten Hosen
genres Alternative Indie Rock Pop
```

my script:

```
 #pip install deezer-python
 import deezer
 id = "88591"
 client = deezer.Client()
 album = client.get_album(id).artist
 genres = client.get_album(id).genres

 print("album", album)
 print("genres", genres)
```

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should `print()` the text in your preferred format by simply parsing the string:

```
import deezer
id = "88591"
client = deezer.Client()
album = client.get_album(id).artist
genres = client.get_album(id).genres

prettyAlbum = str(album)[9:len(str(album))-1]

print("album", prettyAlbum)


prettyGenres = ""

for i in genres:
  prettyGenres += str(i)[8:len(str(i))-1] + " "

print(prettyGenres)
```